# How to reference multiple fields in a lookup table SQLite

Tags: sqlite, lookup

I have two tables. the employee (lookup) table has employeeNum (key) and employeeId plus other fields. The orders (primary) table has order_nbr, cashier_id, cashout_id, and driver_id. These all include matches to employeeNum in the employee_tbl table.

Orders_tbl_______order_nbr_______cashier_id______driver_id
employees_tbl____EmployeeNum_____employeeID

How can I show cashier name, cashout name and driver name in an orders report?  I believed coded correctly but at run, the order, date and time fields are not recognized.   If I remove the "o" in the FROM "Orders_tbl o", then error moves to cant recognize o.order_number

SELECT
"orders_tbl"."order_number" AS "Order",
DATE("orders_tbl"."order_entry_date") AS "Date",
"orders_tbl"."order_entry_time" AS "Time",

```
"orders_tbl".order_number,
"orders_tbl".cashier_id, 
e2.employeeID as cashier_name,
"orders_tbl".cashout_id, 
e3.employeeID as cashout_name,
"orders_tbl".driver_id, 
e4.employeeID as driver_name,


CASE 
 WHEN  SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" THEN "on-line"
 ELSE "employees_tbl"."employeeID"
END "Cashier",

CASE
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashout_id" = 0 THEN "pd online"
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashout_id" <> 0 THEN "Orders_tbl"."cashier_id" 
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) = "WEB" AND "Orders_tbl"."cashier_id" = 0 THEN "employees_tbl"."employeeID" -- should be employee name for cashout for web pay at counter, but comes up 0
 WHEN SUBSTR("orders_tbl"."customer_print_name",1,3) <> "WEB" THEN "employees_tbl"."EmployeeID"
 ELSE  "CASHOUT"
END "Cashout",
```

--    CASE
--     WHEN "orders_tbl"."driver_id" <> 0 THEN "orders_tbl"."driver_id"
--    END "Driver",

```
"orders_tbl"."customer_print_name" AS "Customer",

CASE "orders_tbl"."order_type"
 WHEN 1 THEN "Take-out"
 WHEN 2 THEN "Dine-in"
 WHEN 3 THEN "Delivery"
 ELSE ""
```

END "Type",

```
"orders_tbl"."ord_total" AS "Order $",

CASE "orders_tbl"."discount"
 WHEN 0 then ""
 ELSE "$"||discount
END "Disc. $"
```

--    "Order_Items_tbl"."item_qty" AS "Qty",
--    "Order_Items_tbl"."actual_charge" * "Order_Items_tbl"."item_qty" AS "SubTot $",
--    "Order_Items_Tbl"."item_desc" AS "Item"
FROM orders_tbl

left join employees_tbl e2
on "orders_tbl".cashier_id = e2.employeeNum
left join employees_tbl e3
on "orders_tbl".cashout_id = e3.employeeNum
left join employees_tbl e4
on "orders_tbl".driver_id = e4.employeeNum

WHERE ("orders_tbl"."record_type" = 1 OR "orders_tbl"."record_type" = 5 OR "orders_tbl"."record_type" = 6)
AND "orders_tbl"."voided_order" = 0
AND date("orders_tbl"."order_date") BETWEEN date('now','-3 days','localtime') AND date('now','localtime')

ORDER BY "orders_tbl"."order_date" DESC

looking for syntax error which might be causing this